how do you summarize percentage usage data in pandas data frame groupby a column
I need to count the occurunce of percentage usage by Server name. I have this data frame.
df

Server     Bandwidth  1-Jun  6-June 12-Jun  1-Jul
ServerA    10000      5000    6000    7500    8000
ServerB    100000     60000   80000   75000   80000
ServerC    20000      5000    6000    7500    8000
ServerD    30000      5000    6000    7500    8000
ServerF    10000      5000    6000    7500    8000
ServerX    5000       5000    6000    7500    8000

1st. I need to calculate the percent usage per month given the Bandwidth.
cols=df.columns(difference(['Server','Bandwidth'], sort=false
out=df[cols].div(df['Bandwidth'], axis=0, combine_first(df)[list(df)]

I get this output:
out

Server     Bandwidth  1-Jun  6-June 12-Jun  1-Jul
ServerA    10000      0.50   0.60    0.75    0.80
ServerB    100000     0.60   0.80    0.75    0.80
ServerC    20000      0.25   0.30    0.38    0.40

etc
Next, I need place the percent usage data into bins, 70%-80%, 80%-90%, 90%-100%, 100%+
resulting data frame needs to be like this:
result_df

Server     Bandwidth  70%-80%  80%-90%  90%-100%  100%+
ServerA    10000      1        1        0          0
ServerB    100000     1        2        0          0
ServerC    20000      0        0        0          0

etc
How can I count the occurence of percentage group by Server in pandas?

Your code has typos. Please [edit] to fix them.

Pivot to tidy format where you have columns server, date, and utilisation. Then create a category column with pd.cut. Pivot via group by server and count.

@ifly6 Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead :)

I reshape by use of stack (I just find this more intuitive than melt and like functions):
ndf = df.set_index(['Server', 'Bandwidth']).stack() \
    .reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2': 'date', 0: 'usage'})

Then create the categories using pd.cut (you can put your multiplication by 100 on the utilisation line; if you do that remove it from the pd.cut line):
ndf['utilisation'] = ndf['usage'] / ndf['Bandwidth']
ndf['cat'] = pd.cut(ndf['utilisation'] * 100, [70, 80, 90, 100, np.inf], right=False)

Pass parameter right=False to not include the right-side of the bin. I use np.inf to create a bin for values above 100. The data frame now looks like this:
     Server  Bandwidth    date  usage  utilisation           cat
0   ServerA      10000   1-Jun   5000     0.500000           NaN
1   ServerA      10000  6-June   6000     0.600000           NaN
2   ServerA      10000  12-Jun   7500     0.750000  [70.0, 80.0)
3   ServerA      10000   1-Jul   8000     0.800000  [80.0, 90.0)
4   ServerB     100000   1-Jun  60000     0.600000           NaN
5   ServerB     100000  6-June  80000     0.800000  [80.0, 90.0)
6   ServerB     100000  12-Jun  75000     0.750000  [70.0, 80.0)
7   ServerB     100000   1-Jul  80000     0.800000  [80.0, 90.0)
8   ServerC      20000   1-Jun   5000     0.250000           NaN
9   ServerC      20000  6-June   6000     0.300000           NaN
10  ServerC      20000  12-Jun   7500     0.375000           NaN
11  ServerC      20000   1-Jul   8000     0.400000           NaN
12  ServerD      30000   1-Jun   5000     0.166667           NaN
13  ServerD      30000  6-June   6000     0.200000           NaN
14  ServerD      30000  12-Jun   7500     0.250000           NaN
15  ServerD      30000   1-Jul   8000     0.266667           NaN
16  ServerF      10000   1-Jun   5000     0.500000           NaN
17  ServerF      10000  6-June   6000     0.600000           NaN
18  ServerF      10000  12-Jun   7500     0.750000  [70.0, 80.0)
19  ServerF      10000   1-Jul   8000     0.800000  [80.0, 90.0)
20  ServerX       5000   1-Jun   5000     1.000000  [100.0, inf)
21  ServerX       5000  6-June   6000     1.200000  [100.0, inf)
22  ServerX       5000  12-Jun   7500     1.500000  [100.0, inf)
23  ServerX       5000   1-Jul   8000     1.600000  [100.0, inf)

Then I aggregate on server and category, counting a single column (which specific column is used doesn't actually matter).
>>> ndf.groupby(['Server', 'cat'])['utilisation'].count().unstack()
cat      [70.0, 80.0)  [80.0, 90.0)  [90.0, 100.0)  [100.0, inf)
Server                                                          
ServerA             1             1              0             0
ServerB             1             2              0             0
ServerC             0             0              0             0
ServerD             0             0              0             0
ServerF             1             1              0             0
ServerX             0             0              0             4

You can map your bandwidth back in by concatenating a series to the final data frame on the index, though I don't entirely see why you need it.

Good method. I'd recommend adding labels= within pd.cut() to obtain column headers similar to desired output.

@ifly6, how do you convert ndf back to data frame

ndf is a data frame

need to remove cat and rename the column names

ndf.reset_index(); easiest way to rename columns would be to generate them with the wanted names by passing them with labels= in pd.cut as described above

Here's a one liner that gets it done without creating extra columns.
result_df = df.set_index(['Server', 'Bandwidth']).stack().reset_index().assign(rate = lambda x: x[0].div(x['Bandwidth']), bin = lambda x:pd.cut(x['rate'], bins=[0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, np.inf], labels=['70%-80%', '80%-90%', '90%-100%', '100%+'], right=False)).groupby(['Server', 'Bandwidth', 'bin'], observed=True)['bin'].count().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

result_df

     Server  Bandwidth  70%-80% 80%-90% 100%+
0   ServerA      10000        1       1     0
1   ServerB     100000        1       2     0
2   ServerF      10000        1       1     0
3   ServerX       5000        0       0     4


thank you for your answer. I get this error: TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is ot already an existing category

Hmmm. Does the error provide any other information? Like a column name?

No, df.dtypes have Server as object, everthing else is float64

Odd, I also have Server as object but the rest are int64. I'm starting off with the original dataset. df = pd.DataFrame({'Server': ['ServerA', 'ServerB', 'ServerC', 'ServerD', 'ServerF', 'ServerX'],  'Bandwidth': [10000, 100000, 20000, 30000, 10000, 5000],  '1-Jun': [5000, 60000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000],  '6-June': [6000, 80000, 6000, 6000, 6000, 6000],  '12-Jun': [7500, 75000, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500],  '1-Jul': [8000, 80000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000]})

I converted all but Server into Int64, I am still getting that categorical error.

could you please use the code from my comment to recreate your df and see if it still causes the issue?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
